# Accessing parent view's properties from a child one(using yield helper)

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way I can access parents view's properties from a yielded component. Here is a jsbin of what I was trying to do : http://jsbin.com/buyiq/1/

So my components are defined as :

```
        App.QuestionViewComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
            layoutName: "components/quesiton-view",
            templateName: "components/confirm-delete",
            actions: {

            }

        });

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/confirm-delete">
        <div>Are you sure you want to delete {{question.name}}?</div>

    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/quesiton-view">
       <div>{{question.name}}</div>
       {{yield}}
    </script>
```

In the confirm delete component, I wanted to access the question property of the containing parent component(question-view). How can I achieve this?

Thanks,
Dee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context of `components/confirm-delete`, is each question object passed in the `each`.

So just change it to:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/confirm-delete">                 
  <div>Are you sure you want to delete {{name}} ?</div>    
</script>
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/buyiq/2/edit) is the updated jsbin